# What is the difference between `while (true)` vs `while (\true)`?

Tags: php

What is the difference  between `while (true)` vs `while (\true)` and most Importantly can  anyone clarify why `boolean` are affected by namespace in `PHP` ?

Comment: https://github.com/igorw/retry/issues/3 - *"This already looks a bit better. But there is a rather inefficient FETCH_CONSTANT instruction right at the top. This requires doing a namespace lookup against igorw\true. We can optimize that, by replacing while (true) with while (\true).

This gets rid of the FETCH_CONSTANT call, and puts the boolean true inline:"*

Comment: `TRUE/FALSE` would behave like other constants http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php

Comment: All functions/classes/variables/constants/etc are namespaced in PHP since version 5.3.0, and true/false/null/etc are constants, just like any constants you might define yourself.... most of them are in the global namespace, but PHP will check current namespace first and then check global namespace if it doesn't find them in the current namespace, so using that `\` prefix prevents the overhead of a current namespace check

Comment: @Fred-ii- `NikiC` Just confirmed that `FETCH_CONSTANT` was called due to a [bug in the implementation](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/19080928#19080928)

Comment: @Baba Glad to know the bug has been pinpointed. Thanks for the update.

Comment: @Chris TBH, I'd rather let Baba ask me if he wishes my comment be an answer. Doesn't matter to me really. The main thing is that Baba found out why; a bug in the implementation. *Cheers*

Comment: @Chris NikiC's come up with a great answer. You're welcome to put one in ;) I'll sit this one out.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In PHP `true`, `false` and `null` are constants, which are protected from being overwritten in namespaces. As such the following is invalid code:

```
namespace Foo;
const true = false; // Cannot redeclare constant 'true'
```

It is still possible to overwrite such a constant using ''define()'':

```
namespace Foo;
define('Foo\true', false);
var_dump(true); // bool(false)
```

However this isn't supported functionality (it might be called a bug) and PHP is free to assume that `true` cannot be overwritten. For example usage of `true` in a constexpr context will not be affected by the above definition:

```
// Note: This uses eval() to make sure the define() runs before the constexpr
//       constant resolution happens

namespace Foo;
define('Foo\true', false);
var_dump(eval('namespace Foo;
static $t = true;
return $t;')); // bool(true)
```

The reason why the substitution happens in the constexpr case, but not in the "normal" case is a bug in the implementation. For constexprs the substitution happens before name resolution, whereas for normal code it happens after name resolution.

The correct implementation would be to always substitute after name resolution, but specifically account for `true`, `false` and `null` during the substitution. I plan to fix this for PHP 7.

Comment: @tftd Can't tell if you're being sarcastic. You do know that PHP 7 is the next version of PHP right? We're skipping 6.

Comment: I was rather joking... I didn't know php was going to skip 6 and go straight to 7, though. I'll be watching github for alphas, betas and early snapshots in that case! :)

Comment: I bet there are already eager publishers publishing PHP 7 books, so when that version doesn't ship all that's promised, we can just skip straight to 8!